# Smarty error on webserver

Tags: smarty

I've made a website by Smarty templating engine and appear this error only on server

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file      
smarty/templates_c\wrt53346bde790e08_38443293 <-- thrown in  
D:\Inetpub\webs\casasorgenteit\site_new\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php  
on line 44
```

I've changed the permission but nothing.In local the website works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens in case of wrong permissions. You are saying that you have checked the permissions.

I can see something odd in the file path

smarty/templates_c\wrt53346bde790e08_38443293

There are two different type of slashes in path. Are you testing on windows in dev and linux on prod or vice versa? I guess that might be the source of problem

Comment: Yes is the type of slashes. Is there an algorithm to automatically replace the correct slashes in php?

Comment: you can DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to know the kind of slashes on your system

Comment: you should also explore realpath function